# Ковариантность через инвариантный параметр

Tags: c#

Есть конструкция вот такого вида

```
class TypeBase { }

class TypeConcrete : TypeBase { }

interface IGeneric<T> { }

class Generic<T> : IGeneric<T> where T: TypeBase { }
```

И требуется сделать такое приведение

```
IGeneric<TypeConcrete> someObject = new Generic<TypeConcrete>();
IGeneric<TypeBase> castedObject = someObject;
```

Сейчас это мешает сделать инвариантность параметра T. И было бы хорошо, если бы в интерфейсе был написан out. Но можно ли что-то сделать, если его там нет?

Comment: Никак. Если `IGeneric<T>` принимает параметр типа `T` или имеет сеттер типа `T`, то вы смогли бы нарушить типобезопасность, будь такое хоть как-то возможно.

Comment: out как раз для этого и введен, чтобы показать (и чтоб компилятор мог на это рассчитывать и проверять это), что T может использоваться только в выходных значениях, раз out нет, значит T может быть как в выходных, так и в входных значениях, поэтому такое приведение запрещено.